# How to suppress the JPEG comment created by imagejpeg?

Tags: php, image, comments, jpeg

In a php application, I took over JPG files are created using the "imagejpeg" function. In each of these files, there is a comment like *"CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 90"*. Now our company security guidelines demand blocking for images containing comments. So I am trying to generate JPGs without a comment.

I searched the web, but I couldn't find a way to stop gd from adding this comment. Is it possible at all or do I to have to use another library or the like?

Comment: I don't think you can remove it, because that text like copyright of the library. you can use an alternative way.

Comment: @LionKing I think, OP is reverencing to _technical_ possibility of removing JPEG's comment. That is possible, see answers below. Quite different thing is, if one has _legal right_ to remove such comment, and in this case, you're right. Removing such comment can be taken as violation of copyrights of library used to create an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO it is impossible to block it, only remove using Imagick:

```
$img = new Imagick('input.jpg');
$img->stripImage();
$img->writeImage('output-imagick.jpg');
$img->destroy();
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I decided to use Imagick to create the JPGs. So i don't have to remove something that i don't need. :-)